# Differentiate functions calls in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

Lets say I've my main module with a function `main(x)`
It does its stuff and calls function `foo(y)` which is in other module deeper in the code.

And lets say it was called twice:

so someone called: `main(5)` and someone else `main(8)`

is there a way in the module of function `foo` to know which invoked it?
i.e. the call of `main(5)` or `main(8)`

I'm asking because `foo` doesn't care about the number `5` or `8` so I don't want it to take it as a parameter.

I'm looking for something globally: maybe in the `process` object. 
I couldn't fine any.

---

I'm asking because Im working with Express. Each request has its own request id. I want to log it all the way down without the need to pass a request id to all of my functions because they need it only for logging so it will be ugly

Comment: maybe modify it to `foo(x,y)` if you need to know `x` within `foo`

Comment: Far too vague. Please describe a real-world scenario that shows why you want to do this.

Comment: @AndrewLi and how this helps me to know the correct one inside the module of foo?

Comment: @YardenST Oh, I read the question wrong, whoops.

Comment: @JLRishe thanks added more stuff

Comment: "*`foo` doesn't care about the number `5` or `8`*" - so you don't need to differentiate between the calls?!

Comment: @Bergi look at my answer to understand the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good solution:

**main.js**

```js
let domain = require('domain');
let foo = require('./foo');
let main = function (x) {
    foo();
};

let d1 = domain.create();
let d2 = domain.create();

d1.y = "domain1";
d2.y = "domain2";

d1.run(function () {
    main(5)
});
d2.run(function () {
    main(2)
});
```

**foo.js**

```js
let domain = require('domain');

module.exports = function () {
    console.log(process.domain.y);
};
```

So for the Express users just do:

```js
app.use('*', function(req, res, next) {
  const d     = domain.create();
  d.yourRequestData=req.requestId; //or whatever you need
  d.run(next);
});
```

And now all your code can access the relevant domain and use the requestId for instance.

Credit: BenL

Answer (score 0):

Storing the value globally is not the way to go because you could have a single process handling multiple requests concurrently.

One approach you could use is to place `foo()` within an object that internally contains any values you need to log, like this:

**`foo()` module**

```
module.exports = function (requestId) {

    function internalFunction() {
        writeToLog(requestId, "text to log");
        // do some stuff
    }

    function foo() {
        internalFunction();
    }

    function foo2() {
        internalFunction();
    }

    // external functions
    return { foo, foo2 };
};
```

**`main()` module**

```
function main(requestId) {
    let fooProvider = fooModule(requestId);

    fooProvider.foo();
}
```

Comment: Thats pretty much the solution I was thinking about (but more elegant). But would prefer to have something globally and not passed. If it was threads i could use the thread id for example